# invalid scope error while passing new URL in service account

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

i did some code to hit the Youtube URL by using google service account.what i passed scope is getting 5 records list.but now i changed the scope it showing "invalid_scope"

Error is:

"error_description" : "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos is not valid scope."

```
here my code is:

//Passing ServiceAccount details
            String EmailId = "test@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            List<String>scops = new <String>ArrayList();
              //scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");
              scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos");
            //scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner");

            final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
            final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(EmailId)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scops)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("test.p12"))
            .build();
            System.out.println("credential............."+credential);
            YouTube youtube=new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("test").build();

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id");
            System.out.println("Search list............."+search);
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            System.out.println("SearchResponce.........."+searchResponse);

Here i dont knw wt i did wrong,please any one help me to resolve this issue..its accepting "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner" this url only.
```

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube data API does not support service accounts. You'll have to use oAuth if you need to do writes(including uplaods), or just get an API key and use the Google API client `(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java`) for reading data (no auth needed outside of your API key).

Comment: hi jlmcdonald,i followed by this way(wt ever ur giving url) no auth needed outside of your API key,but it showing the error:There was a service error: 403 : Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Comment: That's a message that you get if your API key is invalid or wasn't properly passed with the request. The first thing to try troubleshooting is to make a request to one of the endpoints just in your browser, appending the API key as a parameter to the URL. If that works, then we can figure out why the client isn't passing it to the request.